# css: при использовании двух div блоков в контейнере с column-count = 2 блоки выводятся друг за другом вертикально, а не горизонтально

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

При использовании двух div блоков в контейнере с column-count = 2 блоки выводятся друг за другом вертикально, а не горизонтально

```css
.blocks {
    width           : 100%;  
    column-count    : 2;
    column-gap      : 0px;

    margin-top      : 15px;

    background-color: red;
}

.blocks > div {
    display         : inline-block;

    height          : fit-content;
    width           : calc(100% - 2 * 1px - 10px);
    
    margin-bottom   : 10px;  
    padding         : 10px 0 10px 10px;
    
    border          : 1px solid black;    
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class='blocks'>
  <div>Block #1</div>
  <div>Block #2</div>
</div>
```

Если же выводить 3 блока - то всё корректно более-менее, хотя всё равно второй блок располагается под первым, а не справа от первого

```css
.blocks {
    width           : 100%;  
    column-count    : 2;
    column-gap      : 0px;

    margin-top      : 15px;

    background-color: red;
}

.blocks > div {
    display         : inline-block;

    height          : fit-content;
    width           : calc(100% - 2 * 1px - 10px);
    
    margin-bottom   : 10px;  
    padding         : 10px 0 10px 10px;
    
    border          : 1px solid black;    
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class='blocks'>
  <div>Block #1</div>
  <div>Block #2</div>
  <div>Block #3</div>  
</div>
```

В чём может быть дело и как это исправить?

Comment: А почему бы просто не использовать `display: grid`? Вместо `width: calc(100% - 2 * 1px - 10px)` можно было бы просто `width: 100%` и `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: Потому что колонки так работают. Во вторую колонку элементы будут перемещаться только после заполнения первой. Т.к. у вас `.blocks` не ограничен по высоте, то заполнятся они будут в следующем порядке: во второй колонке количество будет меньше или равно. Грубо говоря, общее количество делится на 2, число элементов с округлением вверх идёт в первую, остаток во вторую. Попробуйте добавить больше блоков. В случае с двумя блоками оба идут в первую колонку. Если необходимо вывести два блока в две колонки, ограничьте `.blocks` по высоте `height: 50px;`.

Comment: Ну и надо понимать, что колонки созданы для текста, а не распределения `div` блоков. Так с текстом замечательно будет работать `column-fill: balance;`, но на `div` никак не отразится. Чтобы тасовать `div`, как подсказал @OliverPatterson используйте `display: grid`.

Comment: По крайней мере в [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns) вижу только использование с параграфами, но могу быть дико не прав. Использовать `div` довольно интересный подход, здорово, что он работает, но работает не так как вы хотите )

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, `grid` не подходит для работы с блоками одинаковой ширины, но РАЗНОЙ ВЫСОТЫ, потому что сетка как раз по высоте фиксирована, а не хотелось бы чтоб скажем блоки 100px, 75px и 200px имели разные вертикальные отступы

Comment: @DiMithras, согласен, но проблемы начинают возникать если блоки разной высоты, Grid для этого подходит слабо, т.е. хотелось бы чтоб блоки легли "плотно", следующий начинался бы под предыдущим, а не с некоторым отступом

Comment: Про разную высоту вы ранее ничего не писали в вопросе, но я так понимаю хотите добиться чего-то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191329/css-keep-divs-in-columns-aligned)?

Comment: Скорее всего автор хочет что-то типо `masonry`.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, да, именно, 'masonry' - т.е. плотную упаковку блоков разной высоты

Comment: Тогда надо **masonry** использовать, нет?

Comment: да, просто не знал что такая вещь существует и как называется, посмотрел в сети - то, что нужно!